# High beam failure on Toyota Corolla 2010

Tags: toyota, headlight, corolla

The other morning driving to work when I turned on the high beams both were out. The low beams and fog lights are working fine.Could it be a fuse or connection.

Comment: Mine have done the same thing, but the Day Time Running lights don't work either? I have checked the fuses and they seems fine. Could both bulbs burn out at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Fuses only blow if there is either a fault in the circuit causing an excessive current to flow, or due to age and stress the fuse-able link inside them cracks.  The first thing to check is the fuse, but if it has blown, a new one may blow when you turn the light on again.  If the fuse hasn't blown, it could be a faulty main beam switch (possible), a faulty relay (more likely), a broken wire (less likely), a corroded connector (possible), or both bulbs have blown (probably at different times but you didn't notice the first one).
Start with the easy things to check, like the bulbs and relay, then move onto the connectors and switch.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fuse or you could be un-lucky and both bulbs could have blown on high beam.